# "Open Source Routing Machine" querying and parsing

Tags: python-2.7, json, open-source-routing-machine

What I have in Python:

```
import requests
url_osrm = 'http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=50.12345,8.12345&loc=50.23456,8.23456'
print url_osrm
proxies = {"http": "http://YOUR-PROXY:8080"}
osrm = requests.get(url_osrm, proxies=proxies)
print osrm.text
```

---

Question A: How many requests can I send until I get blocked?

---

Question B: How can I extract the first lon/lat from the json-output?

Comment: Please edit your question and only ask one question at a time. Ask a additional question for your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question A: How many requests can I send until I get blocked?**

There is not a fixed limit. It is recommended to use a valid user-agent that you register before hand. This way it is less likely to get blocked. So write an Email to  OSRM (infoATproject-osrm.org), explain them what you want to do, and give them the name of your user-agent.

In your python code this will look like this:

```
import requests
start = '50.12345,8.12345'
stop = '50.23456,8.23456'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Your User-Agent verification'}
url = 'http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=' + start + '&loc=' + stop
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Question B: How can I extract the first lon/lat from the json-output?**

To get the entire json:

```
data = response.json()
```

To get the via_points:

```
via_points = data['via_points']
```

To get the first one:

```
first_point = via_points[0]
print first_point
>>> 
[50.123558, 8.123524]
```